# Unity - Ball bouncing

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Setup for the models]

[image: setup for Ball and Cube]

My task is to control the ball rolling on 2 cubes without bouncing effect.
***Problem:***
If cube_1 and cube_2 are separated (the left image), the ball works perfectly. But if the cubes overlap (the right image), the ball bounces instantly when colliding the cube.
***Question:***
 - Does the ball have default physical material (bouncing, etc)?
 - If yes, how can I disable it?
 - If no, what's wrong in my setup and how should I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the Cubes need to have a Rigidbody?

Comment: @Kale_Surfer_Dude Nice!!! I just removed Rigidbody. It works. But I still don't understand. Could you explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: You usually only need a Rigidbody on something that needs to collide and move with physics. If the cubes are not moving then they don't need one. However, if you do need to move the cubes, you can make the rigidbody checked to "Is Kinematic", and you can move them, but they don't fall with gravity.

Comment: Do your cubes collide with each other? They might jitter in movement without you noticing it so the bull is "kicked away" as soon as it touches the cube